# Run maven test with profiles

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

in Eclipse,
i have a MVN project A that depends on mvn project B-C-D

Project B contains a `mysettings.xml` in wich I have a property like this:
`<iduser>${my.iduser}</iduser>`

I have a maven profile called "deployment" that sets the iduser prop. to "ADMIN".
When I launch a maven clean package specifying "deployment" profile,  in mysettings.xml I find `<iduser>ADMIN</iduser>`

I then created a new profile called "mytest" that sets that property to "TESTUSER".

If I call `mvn -Dtest=MyClassTest -P mytest` on project C, seems like maven does not replace `${my.iduser}` in project B `mysettings.xml` file.

Does anyone know how to get this running in test phase?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven won't do what you're hoping for. The `mysettings.xml` file will get put into Project B's jar file using whatever profile you specified when you built Project B, and the `${my.iduser}` placeholder will be gone (filtered out). It won't come from project B's source directory.

I've never found a satisfactory way to do this with Maven. If `mysettings.xml` is a Spring config file, you can use the [PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) at runtime, rather than Maven filtering at build time.